# Display element from file until a limit value in the file?

Tags: linux, sed, aix

I've a lot of file that looks like :

```
2019-10-28-00-00;/dev/xxx;128.00;106.54;/var/x/x/xxx
2019-10-28-06-00;/dev/xxx;128.00;106.54;/var/x/x/xxx
2019-10-28-12-00;/dev/xxx;128.00;106.54;/var/x/x/xxx
2019-10-28-18-00;/dev/xxx;128.00;106.54;/var/x/x/xxx
2019-10-29-00-00;/dev/xxx;128.00;106.54;/var/x/x/xxx
2019-10-29-06-00;/dev/xxx;128.00;106.54;/var/x/x/xxx
2019-10-29-12-00;/dev/xxx;128.00;106.54;/var/x/x/xx
2019-10-29-18-00;/dev/xxx;128.00;21.46;/var/x/x/xxx
2019-10-30-00-00;/dev/xxx;128.00;21.46;/var/x/x/xxx
```

I would like to display the content of my files until the pattern " 2019-10-29-12-00 "

I've try :

```
sed -n '/2019-10-29-12-00/,/endif/p' file.txt
```

But this command did just the opposite.

I don't know how... Do you have any idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/2019-10-29-12-00/q' file
```

This will print every line up to and including `2019-10-29-12-00`, or

```
sed '/2019-10-29-12-00/Q' file
```

This will print every line up to but not including `2019-10-29-12-00`

Edit: as per user comments.

```
sed '/2019-10-29-12-00/{:a;n;//ba;Q}' file
```

Having found a line containing `019-10-29-12-00` print it and fetch the next line and repeat until the end of file or a line that does not contain `019-10-29-12-00`. The `:a` is the name of the beginning of a loop, the `n` command prints the current line and fetches the next (or if end of file, terminates all sed commands), `//ba` uses the last regexp i.e. `/2019-10-29-12-00/` and if true, breaks to the following loop name i.e. `:a`. `Q` terminates all sed commands but does not print the current line. The `{...}` limits the sed command to the previous regexp.

Comment: Hello ! Thank you for your answer. If I have many lines with "2019-10-29-12-00" at the begin, how to display all the lines including my pattern ? For example, If I have 4 lines with 2019-10-29-12-00 as pattern, I would like that my sed command display and stop when sed find the last line including "2019-10-29-12-00" as the begin ?

Comment: Can you please explain {:a;n;//ba;Q}

Answer (score 2):

Use `1,/pattern/p` to print everything from the beginning to a pattern.

```
sed -n '1,/2019-10-29-12-00/p' file.txt
```

[DEMO](https://ideone.com/zNrnRG)

Comment: @Ezzmazz : If you have a huge file and want to skip "testing" the rest of the file, you can add `;/2019-10-29-12-00/{;q;}` at the end of above. This can save you some time on large files. Good luck to all.

Comment: Hello ! Your command works very well, thank you ! Can I use it if I want to modify all the lines until the 2019-10-29-12-00 pattern with AIX 7.2 ? If think with a for loop ?

Comment: Most `sed` operations can be preceded by an address range like `1,/2019-10-29-12-00/` to perform the operations only on those lines.